# unlock a button with one address (The owner of the smart contract)

Tags: solidity, react

I have a problem to unlock a button under one address and I would like your help, please.

I am doing a DApp of voting. In a first step, I register the voter with theirs Ethereum address:

[image]

In the second screen, the problem is: I don’t succeed to unblock the button when I register a proposal when I repass on the first voter – account4 – from the voter 2 – account5 – , I don’t know why, yet.

[image]

Here are the logs in the console:

[image]

I can show you the relevant code:

Code of the button:

```
 <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>

                                        <Button disabled={this.state.btnWhitelistIsInactive} style={{minWidth:'350px'}} onClick={this.registerANewProposal} variant="dark"> Submit this one! </Button>

                                    </div>
```

Code of my whole App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Voting from "./contracts/Voting.json";
import getWeb3 from "./getWeb3";
import Web3 from "web3";
import "./App.css";


class App extends Component {

    //initialisations
    state = { web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null,
        formError: null,formAddress: null, formProposal: null, ownerOfVotes: null,
        workflowStatusNum: 0, whitelist: [], proposals: [], winningProposalID: null,
        btnWhitelistIsInactive: true};

    /**
     * name: componentDidMount
     * description: initialisation of the application (get the smart contract etc.)
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    componentDidMount = async () => {

        try {

            //get the web3 provider
            const web3 = await getWeb3();

            //using of web3 to get the accounts of the user (in metamask)
            const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

            for(let i = 0; i < this.state.whitelist.length; i++) {
                //if(this.state.whitelist[i].toLowerCase() == accounts[0].toLowerCase()) {
                if(Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(this.state.whitelist[i]) === Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(accounts[0])) {
                    this.setState({btnWhitelistIsInactive: false});
                }
                else{
                    this.setState({btnWhitelistIsInactive: true});
                }
            }
            //get the instance of the smart contract "Voting" with web3 and the informations of deployed file (client/src/contracts/Voting.json)
            const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
            const deployedNetwork = Voting.networks[networkId];

            const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
                Voting.abi,
                deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
            );



            // To avoid the problem of switch accounts in order to refresh the screen
            // related to the account where I am
            window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', (accounts) => {
               // console.log(this.state.whitelist)
                for(let i = 0; i < this.state.whitelist.length; i++) {
                    console.log('this.state.whitelist[i]: ', this.state.whitelist[i]);
                    console.log('accounts[0]: ', accounts[0]);
                    //if(this.state.whitelist[i].toLowerCase() == accounts[0].toLowerCase()) {
                    //this.state.whitelist[i] doesn't seem to move !
                    if(Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(this.state.whitelist[i]) === Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(accounts[0])) {
                        console.log('change state, I am go though the if');
                        this.setState({btnWhitelistIsInactive: false});
                    }
                    else{
                        this.setState({btnWhitelistIsInactive: true});
                    }

                }
                this.setState({accounts});

            });

            // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state, and then proceed with an
            // example of interacting with the contract's methods.
            this.setState({web3, accounts, contract: instance}, this.runInit);
        } catch (error) {
            // Catch any errors for any of the above operations
            alert(
                `Non-Ethereum browser detected. Can you please try to install MetaMask before starting.`,
            );
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    /**
     * name: runInit
     * description: used to start the application, to set the events, do the call etc.
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    runInit = async() => {
        const {contract} = this.state;

        //Get the authorised account list
        const whitelist = await contract.methods.getAddresses().call();
        console.log({whitelist})
        //Get the different proposals written at the first launch of the website and at
        //the refresh of the page
        const proposals = await contract.methods.getProposals().call();

        //Get the winning proposal ID
        const winningProposalID = await contract.methods.getWinningProposalID().call();

        //Get the workflow status
        const workflowStatusNum = parseInt(await contract.methods.getStatusOfWorkflow().call());
        console.log('workflowStatusNum: ', workflowStatusNum);
        let ownerOfVotes = Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(await contract.methods.getOwnerOfVotes().call());
        console.log('Checksum of ownerOfVotes: ', ownerOfVotes);

        //update the state
        this.setState({whitelist, ownerOfVotes, workflowStatusNum, proposals, winningProposalID} );

        //List of the different events defined in the smart contract Voting & application for the DAPP
        //the voter is registered
        contract.events.VoterRegistered().on('data', (event) => this.eventVoterRegistered(event)).on('error', console.error);

        //the workflow status is changed
        contract.events.WorkflowStatusChange().on('data', (event) => this.eventWorkflowStatusChange(event)).on('error', console.error);

        //the proposal is registered
        contract.events.ProposalRegistered().on('data', (event) => this.eventProposalRegistered(event)).on('error', console.error);

        //the vote is registered
        contract.events.Voted().on('data', (event) => this.eventProposalVoted(event)).on('error', console.error);

    }

    /**
     * name: eventVoterRegistered
     * description: manages the information of the list of the registered users in the smart contract
     * @param event
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    eventVoterRegistered = async (event) => {
        const { contract, accounts } = this.state;
        //1 method
        //const updatedWhitelist = whitelist;
        //updatedWhitelist.push(event.returnValues[0]);

        //2e method
        const updatedWhitelist = await contract.methods.getAddresses().call();

        console.log('value of event.returnValues[0]: ', event.returnValues[0]);
        if(Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(event.returnValues[0]) === Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(accounts[0])) {
            this.setState({btnWhitelistIsInactive: false});
        }


           this.setState({ whitelist: updatedWhitelist });
    }

    /**
     * name: RegisterVoter
     * description: registers the voters
     * @param event
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    RegisterVoter = async(event) => {

        event.preventDefault();
        const { accounts, contract } = this.state;
        const address = this.state.formAddress;

        try {
            this.setState({ formError: null });
            //We use the registerVoter method defined in the smart contract
            await contract.methods.registerVoter(address).send({from: accounts[0]});
        } catch (error){
            console.error(error.message);
            this.setState({formError: error.message});
        }
    }

    /**
     * name: eventWorkflowStatusChange
     * description: allows to move in the different states of the workflow defined in Voting.sol
     * @param event
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    eventWorkflowStatusChange = async (event) => {
        const { contract } = this.state;

        const updatedworkflowStatusNum = parseInt(await contract.methods.getStatusOfWorkflow().call());
        this.setState({ workflowStatusNum: updatedworkflowStatusNum });

        //const newWorkflowStatusNum = parseInt(workflowStatusNum) + 1;
        //this.setState({workflowStatusNum: parseInt(newWorkflowStatusNum)});
    }

    /**
     * name: getStatusOfWorkflow
     * description: get the number of status of the workflow where I am
     * @param event
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    getStatusOfWorkflow = async (event) => {

        const { contract } = this.state;

        const workflowStatus = await contract.methods.getStatusOfWorkflow().call();
        console.log('The current status of the workflow is: ', workflowStatus);
    }

    /**
     * name: checkEventProposalsRegistrationStarted
     * description: starts the step, in the workflow, to register the proposals for the voters
     * @param event
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    startProposalsRegistrationSession = async() => {

        const { accounts, contract } = this.state;
        await contract.methods.startProposalRegistrationSession().send({from: accounts[0]});
    }
```

If you have a piece of advice, don’t hesitate to tell me.

Ale

Answer (score 0):

The main idea would be to call your smart contract to know if the current address is whitelisted. So replacing :

```
 for(let i = 0; i < this.state.whitelist.length; i++) {
  console.log('this.state.whitelist[i]: ', this.state.whitelist[i]);
  console.log('accounts[0]: ', accounts[0]);
  //if(this.state.whitelist[i].toLowerCase() == accounts[0].toLowerCase()) {
  //this.state.whitelist[i] doesn't seem to move !
  if(Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(this.state.whitelist[i]) === Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(accounts[0])) {
      console.log('change state, I am go though the if');
      this.setState({btnWhitelistIsInactive: false});
  }
  else{
      this.setState({btnWhitelistIsInactive: true});
  }
}
```

by a simple call to your SC, checking if the current address is white listed. (this is a call, no gas to pay)

```
_btnWhitelistIsInactive = !await contract.isWhiteListed.call({ from: account[0] });
this.setState({btnWhitelistIsInactive: _whiteListIsInactive});
```

There is no need to check against every address. Plus, your contract should not allow state modification from a non white listed address.

Comment: Just edited to make it clear that I mean replace top code by bottom code. Sorry, I didn't see that my answer wasn't very clear.